# How to include above root with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to place my config files above the document root for security reasons and have attempted to do so on my local dev machine (xampp) as well as with bluehost and in both cases `include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../set/include.php')` has failed to find my files in the `/set/` folder which is one level above document root. I've tried most of the options that have come up in the search but I just can't seem to make it work. I am doing this for security but am wondering if there are other options if it MUST be included in webroot? Is there something I am missing such as php.ini modifications, etc.?

Comment: Inspect the value of DOCUMENT_ROOT. There's commonly no trailing path separator.

Comment: `include_once dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/set/include.php';` - might as well make it an absolute path.

Comment: @mario C:/xampp/htdocs is what it shows at home. So technically C:/xampp/htdocs/../set/ would not take me one directory up into the /set/ folder?

Comment: @Jack that puts me inside the webroot...I want to be one level above document root in the /set/ folder.

Comment: How does that put you in the web root exactly?

Comment: @Jack Because DOCUMENT_ROOT for my bluehost is public_html and offline it is htdocs. htdocs in xamp might as well be www/public_html

Comment: `dirname('c:/xampp/htdocs')` yields `'c:/xampp'`, so I don't see how that would stay inside the web root.

Comment: @Jack there is a PHP folder next to htdocs and my PHP folder within htdocs. If all my include paths right now are include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/php/file.php'), then why am I successfully including MY php files and not getting file not found from the php directory above the folder where my index.php is located?

Comment: Please read my first comment again, and again until you notice the use of `dirname()`.

Comment: @Jack Ok my fault I didn't see you wrapped it in dirname.

Comment: @Jack That worked by the way AND translated to bluehost as well. I appreciate your help. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have accomplished this by explicitly setting the path - that is the fully qualified path. This can be done in `.htaccess` or `php.ini` depending on your setup. Then when you include the php file you don't need to specify the path to the file.

On my local host in `.htaccess'

```
php_value include_path ".;c:\desiredpath"
```

On my shared server in `php.ini'

```
include_path = ".:/home/username/desiredpath"
```

Comment: I like this approach even better. Appreciate it.

Comment: My php.ini has an include path set for unix as ".:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear" . Is it ok to overwrite this?

Comment: You can append to the path. Paths are delimited on Unix with a colon and Windows with a semi-colon. So in your case the path would be `".:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear:/usr/php"` or whatever path you want added to the end instead of `/usr/php`. Unless you are not using files in the pear directories mentioned - in that case, just overwrite (backup first in case).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the problem lies here:

```
include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '../set/include.php')
                                           ^
```

It's missing a leading slash, causing a path like `/htdocs../set/include.php`.

That said, you could use [`dirname()`](http://php.net/dirname) so that you can pass an absolute path:

```
include_once dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/set/include.php';
```